# Is it 'ok' to have electrostatic sensitive components on an end-user, exposed PCB design?

Tags: pcb, esd

I'm currently working on an electronics project. This project is intended to be portable and battery powered. I'm curious about whether or not I should use certain components on my PCB do being too ESD sensitive.

For example, I'm currently trying to use [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sitime/SIT8920BM-83-33E-8.000000X/1473-1512-1-ND/5974683) clock on my design. After ordering it, I notice that it came packaged with a warning to only open/handle at an electrostatic-free workstation.

Now obviously I could oblige to this, however, my end design is an exposed PCB in which a user may accidentally touch. The end user (colleagues of mine, not external customers) will be handling this device to press pushbuttons, look at lights, etc. Furthermore, my design only covers the electronic portion thus I can't create an enclosure to protect during operation. That's the end user's duty.

So I'm somewhat concerned as to whether or not I should proceed with using the previously referenced IC. I'm also not sure as to what kind of ESD protection is used on portable electronics that may allow me to use the chip.

So my questions:

- Is there ever a point in which a certain component shouldn't be selected on an open PCB design because it's too ESD sensitive? Or can you just bypass this with appropriate ESD protection?

  - What kind of ESD proection is used for portable electronics?

Comment: Yes, any board seen by the customer that has ESD-sensitive devices should have ESD protection on it. ESD protection is usually done using TVS diodes

Comment: Consider that these components are tied into other components with multiple, tiny protection diodes, resistors, capacitors, etc., all tied into the same nodes. It's also difficult to reach or touch certain areas, too. If you have any really high impedance nodes, even getting close can be a problem. But often, then adding static zap or efield protection to those nodes ruins their performance, too. So in some cases you'll see mental cans soldered around those areas. Use your judgment but also do some testing and make adjustments when you find problems.

Comment: @jonk: I understand it's a typo, but thinking of ***mental*** cans to protect ESD sensitive device is really hilarious! You made my day, man! :-D

Comment: @LorenzoDonati ;) They are often used in conjunction with tin foil hats!

Comment: @jonk Yep! Indeed! Especially against aliens (or the NSA) using the infamous Extra-Sensory Detection technology! :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will **always** be a certain ESD level which can damage your product. The question is, how much protection do you need so that it is "good enough" ?

For (portable) consumer products the sensitive points are all the conductive / metal contacts which are exposed. So for a mobile phone, you would use TVS diodes or such to implement extra protection on the charging port and headphone socket for example. That is not to say that there would be **no** protection without these extra diodes ! There is always ESD protection in any modern IC but it will be a lower level protection, it can handle ESD but not too much. For example: 500 V HBM (Human Body Model).

This level of protection (500 V HBM for example) would be enough for handling that crystal oscillator you ordered **in a somewhat ESD safe environment**. With this I mean, precautions have been taken to keep ESD pulses at a low level. For example: a conductive and grounded ESD mat and the user grounded by wearing an ESD wrist band.

Don't draw too much of a conclusion about ESD sensitivity by looking at the packaging or warnings companies like mouser use. If you would order **resistors** I bet they would also come in ESD safe packaging and might also come with a warning although resistors are not ESD sensitive.

Regarding your PCB, since it is not a consumer product and you can expect the user to know that (s)he should not be poking his/her finger everywhere and generate ESD discharges. In my experience the build-in ESD protection of most ICs is sufficient and will provide enough protection for normal usage by a user who is aware of ESD.

So if you have external connections on your board: use extra protection.

For the part that the user should not touch anyway: no extra protection needed.

Comment: 500V is insufficient for many parts of the world where humidity can be low so 1kV and 3kV is used for components  and 15kV for system tests with ESD

Comment: The 500 V was just an **example**. Maybe you always use 1, 3 and 15 kV, that does not mean everyone else **must** do the same.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Many resistors are actually ESD sensitive in that an ESD pulse can cause their value to drift out of tolerance.  Vishay has some good app notes on this advertising their ESD immune metal foil resistors.

Comment: @FakeMoustache in my experience from auditing the design and test processes of dozens of large companies like the one I was in at the time. They were generally consistent  with our practice for quality products. This is the error of many low tech Chinese companies and DIY designers alike yet even the Chinese have more advanced test methods in certain areas, so this is not menat to slur all chinese products as they have one of 2 highest 2GV power transmission systems in the world in R&D and longest 1.5kV  I can dig up the IEC standards if you like to compare on susceptibilty

Comment: @user96037 Sure for **precision resistors** that could make sense. But I was talking about the cheap 1% or 5% tolerance resistors we all use when precision is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell you a story.

In the early 80's all keyboards would have tiny red LEDs exposed and customers found their keyboards would die for no reason. Our company did research on our computer products and tested every new product with a Schaefer 15kV to 25kV ESD generator to simulate the human finger or cart model and found the zap could be silent and not felt by a user going past the exposed 5mm LED to the leads and either anode or cathode connect to CMOS logic could trigger an SCR latchup effect which could cause the so-called ESD protected CMOS to burnup ( internal short, not flames) from an SCR crowbar in the sublayer of all CMOS.

Since then all LED's were buried well below the surface and used light pipes to prevent this or very long epoxy bodies just below a plastic surface guard.

If you do not test your product for ESD susceptibility or design it to withstand 1 hundred random discharges @ 15kV from 300pF, to all user accessible interfaces

... you can expect failures unless the user is given clear instructions how to avoid this and accept the consequences of failure.

- I have dozens of similar stories of ESD failures at embarrassing times.

One day (1982) we were in a customer (MTS) owned "test home" with all our newly invented technology aka Project IDA, that offered digital telephony, pay-Tv , fire/burglar alarms , tele-shopping with remote keyboard, online TV opinion polling in real-time, digital weather maps, high speed serial ports in the phone jacks with dual RF TV converters outside on the poles and a whole 2 way 1.544 Mb sync modem to every home in the trial. Then the Mayor of St Louis was interested and brought his group for a demo and when the demonstrator touched the TV it conducted ESD to the motherboard in the basement and reset the unit into a fault mode, recovered by power cycling.  ( so after quickly power cycling it .. dry winter in Winnipeg, the demo resumed)  ( Mayor never bough it and was just trying to steal the technology to buy votes for next election) it ended up being sold off to a company that own Scientific Atlanta, Mattel, Intelivision etc. in Phili.PA and the company was bankrupt ahead of its time.

Next day we had 3 fixes for the ESD event to never happen again with improved ground shift immunity with CM choke , better grounding etc.

Comment: I remember using those generators to test board designs against ESD!

Comment: I designed another test with 15kV impulse to a flat sheet of metal for E-Wave impulse test at 1m into our Corporate standard while the UHF radiated immunity was too weak without modulation so I added 1kHz AM to the wide spectrum immunity tests.

Comment: Yah but the Shaeffer was pretty tame compared to a Tazer these days or even better neoprene shoes in a dry winter day in a hotel room with Nylon carpets. I remember creating 3" arcs with a key to the door knob or >75mm  or > 75kV.. recently when I was testing MVA distribution transformers for a client/factory owner up to 200kV , I had no fear of climbing up on top of the unit and connecting the wires to the bushing, but I would touch the wires submersed in oil with remanence as they continued to keep on giving zaps, long after disconnect.. a job for the factory workers.

Comment: Wow. You can get nice, hard xrays with 75 kV. (Dental uses a mere 70 kV, typically, on the rotating tungsten target.) Which is something else that a lot of people forget when they are messing around with high voltages for huge arcs in air.

Comment: You can get Gamma rays at 15kV if the rise time in in picoseconds so it not voltage dependent , rather dI/dt.  They use 1GHz detectors for PD in Transfos also UV and a few researchers in Gamma but UHF gives best results for internal ESD in oil called Partial Discharge or PD. there are about 10k thesis papers on this topic alone

Comment: A consultant our company hired in the early 80's showed me how he captured an ESD event with 6ps rise time. amazing

Comment: I'm still struggling to see how that can occur, getting a gamma from 15 kV, given that a gamma ray _starts_ with energies of a few hundred keV and goes into MeV. It would require, at a minimum, the magical combination of all of the energies of some 15 electrons at that potential drop all combined into a single photon. Can you describe the detailed mechanism here? I'm just not able to figure it out. The short time might be a clue here. But the mechanism escapes me.

Comment: It comes with the detonation of oil that releases H2 and Methane and further detonation of H2 dissolved in transformer oil which if large enough triggers a chain reaction and the transformer explodes so it has to do with the energy available discharged in dI/dt in molecular size particles.  with very thin film of charges and the double-electric charge layer, 75kV/mm becomes 75V/um and particulate contaminants become the charge carriers.. longer paths under several Tesla magnetic fields accelerate the Kinetic energy of particles which starts the chain reaction

Comment: normally it does not radiate gamma, but if the chain reaction leads to bigger combustible gases like acetylene each with higher activation levels and explosive energy.

Comment: this is why dissolved gas analysis in transformer oil is routinely done and better methods I have researched use PD ( internal ESD) detection with simple high speed 1GHz detectors on a loop wire around the ground connection or microwave internal antenna. I discover that the reason for variation in Breakdown Voltage (BDV) in any dielectric is due to particles or voids in solids like dust  in air or impurity in plastic material. This ΔV in BDV thresh is due to PD or (internal ESD) from the electric field creating a certain higher V/um  in the particle or void. If BDV is constant , there is no PD

Comment: Corona is just the relaxation oscillator effect of PD that occurs inside HiV units and called this when external. If internal, its called PD. If external its called Corona.  It may start from 1ppm to 1pps to 50/60pps and multiples of this

Comment: Sometimes people show appreciation for trivial things on what they already know and neglect the experience of others because they do not understand.  forget the gamma part as I have not verified this myself only recall reading an article...but UV I have verified.

Comment: I enjoy such excursions, even if wrong, because it forces me to think about mechanisms and perhaps into ideas I hadn't considered before about other ways things might occur. There's a lot I don't know and experience sometimes forces me to consider details in new combinations. Enjoyed.

Comment: In this case the owner was facing multi-million dollar lawsuits for non-compliance on DGA/PD. I only charged 10k to fix it. or rather make a list of suggests.. it took yrs and still he's not there yet